check valve before or after water well pressure tank?
I'm installing a water heater (conventional electric storage tank) for a neighbor (to replace a failing tankless unit).  We have individual water wells with pressure tanks.   I'm trying to figure out if there's a check-valve, and if so, if it's before or after the pressure tank.   If it's before the pressure tank (between the pipe from the well pump and the pressure tank) it means that the water heater does not require an expansion tank (the well pressure tank takes care of the expansion issue).
Here's a few pictures of the installation.


If there is indeed a check-valve after the pressure tank (the unfortunate situation requiring an expansion tank on the water water) it's probably the brass piece (shown in closeup on the lower picture with the blue pex attached to it; it looks a little more complicated that just a pex-barb to FNPT adapter, but maybe that's all it is; the numbers on it didn't help.  The check-valve at my house is much larger.
I don't see anything that looks like a check-valve anywhere else in the system, unless it's at the well-head or something.   Or built into the brass piece coming out from the bottom of the tank; it's totally unclear to me what is the thing just below the pressure gauge coming towards the camera.
Anyhow, I'd be grateful for any insight.

There's at least one check valve, and it's in the pump (if submersible) or foot valve (if it's a shallow well pump.) Others would be optional, may cause more harm than good due to hammering between multiple check valves, and if not required by applicable code should not be added williy-nilly. None are shown in these pictures

Is that all sitting above a pan? Is there no existing hot water heater (a true installation vs. a remove/replace)?
The brass piece in your close up is just a fitting. The Pex adapter is a female with a close nipple to connect to the female valve fitting. A male adapter would have been simpler (like the opposite side of the manifold) but sometimes even pros use what they have.
The thing that's unclear to you seems to just be an elaborate plug coming off the manifold. Could be a way to get a future connection/valve further away from the manifold (convenience) or something was once there and removed (seems a low probability since the age of the fitting appear similar).
The copper pipe coming up from the manifold, is that to a recirc pump? A wider view of what we're looking at could be helpful.
I'm a contractor, but not a licensed plumber for what it's worth. Just giving my take on for the sake of offering a somewhat quick answer.

Yeah, the homeowner (stepson) is paranoid about leakage, esp. with his newly-encapsulated crawlspace - hence the pan below the pressure tank.

It's to replace a failing propane-fired tankless unit (those things suck).

The copper pipe coming up from the manifold is going to the pressure-actuated switch for the well pump.

The "thing coming off the manifold" is pretty clearly a 100PSI pressure relief valve. Which is pretty standard to prevent problems with the pressure tank if the pump controller contacts weld closed and it keeps running after it should have stopped. The brass pipe is going to the pump controller (pressure switch.)

Yeah, I should've mentioned that "thing coming off the manifold" had an opening at the bottom that you can't see in mu pic).

So, it seems clear that there's no check-valve (aka. backflow preventer) between the well pressure tank and the house piping (including the new water heater) and therefore I don't need to put an expansion tank on the water heater.   Which begs the question, is there a backflow preventer at all, and if not, is that a problem that should be addressed ?

Congrats on your first accepted answer (apparently), @Ryker Cole !
